# InvalidBSON on MongoDB import - Pandas

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pandas, pymongo

I'm currently working with Pandas (0.14.1) in Python 3.4.2 importing data from a Mongo database using pymongo (2.8). Upon a simple import,

```
cur = db.collection.find()
df = pd.DataFrame(list(cur))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidBSON: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 3123: invalid continuation byte
```

Import note: Previously, I was doing the same tasks (importing the same collections into a pandas dataframe for processing) using pandas in Python 2.7+ and all of the imports worked without issue. For other reasons, I would now prefer to stay in the 3.4+ environment.

While I cannot share the data, I can say it is UTF-8 encoded (which makes the error confusing) line-delimited JSON documents I bulk imported into MongoDB. Some of the fields contain many unicode characters. Up until now, working in the mongo console and python 2.7+ with read-only (from the db) tasks, I have not run into the above problem. As a check, after getting this error in python 3.4, I ran the same code in 2.7 (for the same db collection) and it imported fine.

Is anyone able to provide some insight into what is happening, and perhaps provide some support to remedy the problem? I am willing to provide any additional information I can.

Update:

I identified the offending document using

```
for doc in cur.sort([('_id', 1)]): print(doc['_id'])
```

and taking the _id following the last one listed. However, there is some odd behavior. Specifically, if I create a DataFrame using

```
pd.DataFrame(list(db.collection.find({'_id' : ObjectId('offending _id')}))
```

it works fine. The same document exists in several collections, and throws the error in each one when attempting to import the full collection.

Document:

```
{"app_name" : "Tiles", "description" : "Tiles is a sliding tile puzzle, also known as a \"15 Puzzle\". Using Tiles, you choose photos from your Photo Library on your iPhone or iPod Touch, or use the built-in camera on your iPhone.  Tiles then cuts the photo into tiles and scrambles them into a fun puzzle for you to solve!  Your job is to slide the tiles around and re-assemble the photo!\n\nSee if you can re-assemble the photo in the least number of moves or the fastest time possible!  Challenge your friends to beat your time!  Choose from an infinite number of images you create yourself, and up to 4 different puzzle configurations.\n\nFeatures:\n\n* 9, 16, 25, or 36 Tile Selections\n* Integrated with the built in iPhone camera and Photo Library so you can use your photos for puzzles.\n\nBy Request: A standard \"15\" Puzzle image can be downloaded at http://www.random-ideas.net/Software/Tiles/16.png simply download it and sync it with your phone (via iTunes) touse it.\n\nIn keeping with our company mission, we will be donating 5% of the pre-tax net profits from Tiles to charity.  The selected charity for Tiles will be to benefit autism.\n  \n  \n", "whats_new" : "Fixed a rare crashing bug while selecting a new image.\n  \n  \n"}
```

Comment: Can you track down exactly which document is giving this error and post it to the question?

Comment: The question has been updated with some additional information.

Comment: I think you may be hitting [PYTHON-721](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-721). Can you load the document in the mongo shell? Also, you may have gotten the last working document instead of the first nonworking document - you could try sorting on `_id`, finding the last working document in python, then using the mongo shell to find the next document after that in the same order.

Comment: Ah, it does sound similar. Yes, I can open the affected document in the mongo shell. It's odd that it works fine in Python 2.7+, but raises the error in 3.4.

Comment: I think that means you'll have to sanitize your data, get rid of the bad utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way of applying encoding on a cursor object while directly loading it into pandas. You may want to use mongoexport to dump your data into a csv first:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db dbname --collection name --csv > test.csv
```

...and then you load that data in as utf-8.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding = "utf-8")
```